# Get data from a Form in the beforeSave method of a Model

Tags: forms, cakephp, before-save

I already created a register form.
I have 3 select-boxes. Day, Month, Year.
In my database I have one column called "Birthday" with the format of "date".
Now I want to put all three together and insert the result into the database.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
    $this->data['User']['Birthday'] = $this->data['User']['Year'] . '-' . $this->data['User']['Month'] .'-' . $this->data['User']['Day'];
    return true;
}
```

But this is not working :(

None of this fields (Day, Month,Year, Birthday) has validation rules..

How can I do this?

Comment: Concept looks fine - what error(s) are you getting?  Have you debugged $this->data to see what's actually IN the data?

Comment: Change your inputs to be input('User.Birthday.year') and the same for month and day. If the datatype in the db in a date, cake should re-construct the date inputs to a string automatically. Although, re-constructing it for the view won't be automatic any longer. Why do you just use input('User.Birthday') and set its type to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code in your Model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
   if(!empty($this->data)){
       //pr($this->data);die;
       $this->data['User']['Birthday'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->data['User']['Year'] . '-' . $this->data['User']['Month'] .'-' . $this->data['User']['Day']));
      unset($this->data['User']['Year']);
      unset($this->data['User']['Month']);
      unset($this->data['User']['Day']);
   }
   return true;   
}
```

There must be following form fields should be available into your form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => $this->params));
      echo $this->Form->input('Year', array('options' => $year_options, 'type' => 'select'));
      echo $this->Form->input('Month', array('options' => $month_options, 'type' => 'select'));
      echo $this->Form->input('Day', array('options' => $day_options, 'type' => 'select'));
```

Comment: Why are you doing `strtotime` and then `date`. That's like doing `5 * 2 / 2`

Comment: That is because of if year year dropdown value contains `89` instead of `1989`, then it may create a problem while saving and results to un-dated format. Thats why I used strtotime().